# How to use pk1 and pk2 in Django API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-urls

I'm getting trouble when trying to queryset multiple pks (pk and pk2) in my URL.
I want to do something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [    
path('tableau/<int:pk>/liste/<int:pk2>', views.ListeDetail.as_view()),
]
```

I need a detail view of liste (pk2) contained in a tableau (pk).

So far, here is my class but it does'nt work properly.

```
class ListeDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ListeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset =  Liste.objects.filter(tableau_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
        return queryset
```

Anyone know how to work with multiple pks in the url ?

Comment: For that purpose if you want to list several ids it's better to use query params, like: 
`tableau/list?ids=pk1,pk2`
And than get them in view by `request.query_params`

Comment: Thanks Sergey, but I do not understand, I'm new to Django so looks a little bit tricky. could you show me an example of how to implement it or documentation please ?

Comment: @ChristopherBolard answer updated, check to see if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [    
   path('tableau/<int:tableau_id>/liste/<int:sub_id>', views.ListeDetail.as_view()),
]
```

Here you are dealing with nested resources, you need provide `lookup_url_kwarg` to filter the first level of resource.

```
from rest_framework.generics import get_object_or_404

class ListeDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'tableau_id'  # get your tableau_id
    serializer_class = ListeSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset =  Liste.objects.filter(tableau_id=self.kwargs["tableau_id"])
        return queryset
    
    def get_object(self):
        sub_id = self.kwargs['sub_id']
        # replace subobjects to your `related_name`(reverse) name
        obj = get_object_or_404(Liste.objects.get(tableau_id=self.kwargs["tableau_id"]).subobjects.all(), id = sub_id)
        return obj
```

### EDIT

override the `get_object` method you can adjust the detail view behavior